# Any differences when a signed apk uploaded to Google Play

Tags: android, signature

If I have a signed apk and uploaded to Google Play, I would like to know any differences in the signature data after uploading to Google Play.

I would also like to know why my Android device knows the apk is downloaded from Google Play rather than other markets?

Comment: download directly from google play store, google checks them for viruses, malware, and anything else the company would consider malicious. Then it allows that app and updates to pass through to users. This is how Google makes money off Android. Any third party install will be consider as unknown sources

Comment: I am wondering how my Android device knows it is downloaded from Google Play.

Comment: your device doesn't know if the app is downloaded from google play or other sources, but google play know which apps on your device is downloaded from google play, where is the problem?